# Lots of Email or Lot of Emails?

Tags: grammar

If you are trying to tell someone on an email about the fact that you are sending them too many emails, do you say "**Lots of**" Email or "**A lot of**" Emails?

Comment: "I'm sorry for sending you lots of emails." and "I'm sorry for sending you lots of email." are both okay. The word "email" can be used as a count noun or a non-count noun.

Answer (score 5):

I have seen both, and used both, so I would say neither is obviously incorrect. If you read [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/email#Usage_notes), they note that “certain style guides recommend against the countable use of email” but also that people do it all the time.

I would also just note two other things: Email is an accepted spelling, however so are e-mail, eMail, and email. Second, the root word *mail* is not flexible in this way: you must say *lots of mail*. “Lots of mails” is not incorrect, but very archaic and incorrect sounding.

Comment: Well said... I find "two emails" to be perfectly clear and more succinct than "two email messages". I suspect it's just too new a word for the usage rules to have settled out yet.

Comment: @godel9: I think K.A has the right of it (we've both seen and used both), so in my book that means usage has "settled". I'm not about to be converted by anyone who tries to convince me that either usage is somehow "incorrect". ***Email*** falls into the same category as, say, [tea, coffee, whisky](http://www.englishclub.com/ref/Nouns_that_Are_Countable_and_Uncountable/index.htm). All that remains to be resolved is *when will everyone* abandon those daft hyphen/capital letter affectations.

Comment: Is "eMail" really accepted?  If so, by whom?  I'm unfamiliar with it.

Comment: @snailplane: It's a rare usage compared to others, but I know Steve Gibson/GRC.com uses it.

Answer (score 2):

Why not "too many emails"? That sounds better than either "lots of emails" or "a lot of email".

By the way, I think you would want to say *a lot*, not *lot*. "A lot" means many.

Another way to say it would be "Sorry I've been sending you **so much** email".

I would consider *emails* to be a shortened form of "email messages," so yet another safe way to say it would be "Sorry I've been sending you a lot of email messages."

Answer (score 0):

Email is the shortened version of electronic mail. If you were talking about non-electronic mail, bills, letters and such, you would say 'I receive a lot of mail' and not 'I receive a lot of mails'. Mail is both plural and singular, so email should follow the same rule.

Comment: Mail is neither plural nor singular. It is a [mass noun.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_noun)

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct. 
You can say either:

> I'm sending you **a lot of** emails. ✅

or

> I'm sending you **lots of** emails. ✅

Both are informal styles, but **Lots of** is more informal than **a lot of**.

Reference: [Cambridge dictionary - grammar](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/quantifiers/much-many-a-lot-of-lots-of-quantifiers).